# How to calculate factorial function as $x\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

I need to calculate

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{((2x)!)^4}{(4x)! ((x+5)!)^2 ((x-5)!)^2}.$$

Even I used Striling Approximation and Wolfram Alpha, they do not help.

How can I calculate this?

My expectation of the output is about $0.07$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello! You may wish to read this about inputting formulas: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also: I don't you tried very hard to use Stirling's formula. What have you done?

Comment: As you know, in Striling's approximation, form of "x^x" appeared. I can not calculate this. I just put some positive integers in x

Comment: You will get many such items, but there will be a lot of cancellation.  What do you get when you simplify?

Comment: It is the simplest form of item. The purpose of computation is so complex, I abbreviated them, sorry.

Comment: @Choi, could you compute the limit of $(2x)^{(8x)}/(4x)^{(4x)}$ as $x \to \infty$? You can simplify!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit as given in the problem is equal to zero. This is shown by the following.

Using $\Gamma(1+x) = x \Gamma(x)$ the expression to evaluate is seen as
\begin{align}
\phi_{n} &= \frac{\Gamma^{4}(2n+1) }{ \Gamma(4n+1) \Gamma^{2}(n+6) \Gamma(n-4)} \\
&= \frac{n^{2}(n-1)^{2}(n-2)^{2}(n-3)^{2}(n-4)^{2}}{(n+1)^{2}(n+2)^{2}(n+3)^{2}(n+4)^{2}(n+5)^{2}} \ \frac{\Gamma^{4}(2n+1)}{\Gamma(4n+1) \Gamma^{4}(n+1)}.
\end{align}
Now, by using Stirling's approximation, namely,
\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+1) \approx \sqrt{2 \pi} \ n^{n+1/2} \ e^{-n}
\end{align}
this expression becomes
\begin{align}
\phi_{n} &= \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2}\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{2}
\left(1-\frac{3}{n}\right)^{2}\left(1-\frac{4}{n}\right)^{2}}{
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{2} \left(1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^{2} \left(1+\frac{4}{n}\right)^{2} \left(1+\frac{5}{n}\right)^{2}} \ \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi n} }
\end{align} 
Taking the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ leads to
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Gamma^{4}(2n+1) }{ \Gamma(4n+1) \Gamma^{2}(n+6) \Gamma(n-4)}  = 0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Using directly Stirling approximation of the factorial $$\begin{align}
\Gamma(n+1) \approx \sqrt{2 \pi} \ n^{n+1/2} \ e^{-n}
\end{align}$$ the expression becomes $$\frac{((2x)!)^4}{(4x)! ((x+5)!)^2 ((x-5)!)^2}\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} (x-5)^{9-2 x} x^{4 x+\frac{3}{2}} (x+5)^{-2 x-11}$$ which, for large values of $x$, can be approximated by $$\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}-50 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}
   \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}+1275 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}
   \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{5/2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{7/2}\right)$$

For $x=100$, the exact value is $0.0484141$ while the approximation is $0.0500673$.
For $x=1000$, the exact value is $0.0239969$ while the approximation is $0.0240019$.